# Problem with DDA algorithm when starting point has a lower X/Y value than end point

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to implement the DDA algorithm to determine which cells exist between two points in a 2D grid. This is meant to be used for raycasting in a tile based game.

Below code works well as long as starting coordinates is lower than the ending coordinates however I tried to make it work for every direction by adding a direction modifier for the increment variable (-1 when the algorithm is supposed to go to a cell in the 2D matrix with lower X or Y value).

However it does not give the desired output. Images below to illustrate.

Working code:

```py
import math
import pygame

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

matrix = []

tile_size = 20
w = 38
h = 38

for _ in range(w):
    sub = []
    for _ in range(h):
        sub.append(0)
    matrix.append(sub)

startx = 2
starty = 7
endx = 1
endy = 1

currentx = startx
currenty = starty

dx = endx - startx
dy = endy - starty

if startx > endx:
    x_direction = -1
else:
    x_direction = 1

if starty > endy:
    y_direction = -1
else:
    y_direction = 1    

Sx = math.sqrt(1**2 + (dy/dx)**2)
Sy = math.sqrt(1**2 + (dx/dy)**2)

x_incrementer = 1
y_incrementer = 1

coords_list = []
coords_list.append([startx, starty])


while (currentx != endx) and (currenty != endy):

    if (Sx * x_incrementer) <= (Sy * y_incrementer):
        x_incrementer += 1
        currentx += 1 * x_direction
        coords_list.append([currentx, currenty])
    
    elif (Sx * x_incrementer) > (Sy * y_incrementer):
        y_incrementer += 1
        currenty += 1 * y_direction
        coords_list.append([currentx, currenty])
    
for coord in coords_list:
    matrix[coord[1]][coord[0]] = 1

print("Start: X:",startx, "Y:", starty)
print("End: X:",endx, "Y:", endy)
print("Coordinates:", coords_list)

while not done:

    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill([255,255,255])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    y_counter = 0
    for y in matrix:
        x_counter = 0
        for x in y:

            if x == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,162,232], ((x_counter*tile_size)+tile_size, (y_counter*tile_size)+tile_size, tile_size, tile_size))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0,0,0], ((x_counter*tile_size)+tile_size, (y_counter*tile_size)+tile_size, tile_size, tile_size), 1)

            x_counter +=1
        y_counter +=1
    
    pygame.draw.line(screen, [255,0,0], [(startx*tile_size)+tile_size, (starty*tile_size)+tile_size], [(endx*tile_size)+tile_size, (endy*tile_size)+tile_size], 3)

    clock.tick(60) 
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Image 1: Working as intended (start x/y: 1,1 | end x/y: 2,7)

Image 2: Not working (start x/y: 2,7)

[image: Working as intended (start x/y: 1,1 | end x/y: 2,7)]
[image: Not working (start x/y: 2,7)]

Comment: I would use Bresenhan's Line Algorithm:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Even the (start x/y: 1,1 | end x/y: 2,7) case does not work as intended, because one blue cell is too much. The problems:

1. do not append [startx, starty] befre the loop
2. append [currentx, currenty] before it is changed
3. subtract 1 from `currentx` or `currenty` if the direction is negative, because the left under index is always the index of the following cell

```py
startx = 2
starty = 7
endx = 1
endy = 1

currentx = startx
currenty = starty

dx = endx - startx
dy = endy - starty
Sx = math.sqrt(1**2 + (dy/dx)**2)
Sy = math.sqrt(1**2 + (dx/dy)**2)
x_direction = -1 if startx > endx else 1
y_direction = -1 if starty > endy else 1   

x_incrementer = 1
y_incrementer = 1
coords_list = []
while (currentx != endx) and (currenty != endy):

    x = currentx - 1 if dx < 0 else currentx
    y = currenty - 1 if dy < 0 else currenty
    coords_list.append([x, y])
    if (Sx * x_incrementer) <= (Sy * y_incrementer):
        x_incrementer += 1
        currentx += 1 * x_direction
    else:
        y_incrementer += 1
        currenty += 1 * y_direction
```